# How save text to local storage, and access it and append it to an OL on linked webpage

Tags: javascript, function, variables, local-storage, dom-events

1. I want to capture text from an input on index.html, and save it to local storage.
2. on index2.html i want to get the item from local storage, create a new li, and append that to the empty OL.

the code i currently have always gives me an error "uncaught typeerror: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

So I'm guessing that it's unable to gain access to my OL (which is the ordered variable).

I'm new to this and Im trying to create a note taking app for practice, so what am I doing wrong?

```
let notes = document.querySelector("#note");
let submit = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
let view = document.querySelector(".view-btn");
let ordered = document.querySelector("#notes-list");
let form = document.querySelector("form");


submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    localStorage.setItem("note", notes.value);
    let newLI = document.createElement("li");
    newLI.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("note");
    ordered.appendChild(newLI);
    notes.value = "";
});
```

Comment: Where do you have your javascript code? Before or after the HTML code? Because if you have your javascript code in the HEAD, then it will run before any HTML have been generated, and therefor not find `#notes-list`. It's also sometimes difficult to select `id` tags with hyphens.

Comment: i have it at the end. right before the closing body tag on index.html - Do i also have to put the js file on index2.html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to tell you. This code below seems to work. Perhaps you could double check with your code?

I had to remove the localStorage code, because that doesn't work on Stackoverflow.

```js
let notes = document.querySelector("#note");
let submit = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
let ordered = document.querySelector("#notes-list");

submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let newLI = document.createElement("li");
    newLI.innerHTML = notes.value;

    ordered.appendChild(newLI);
    notes.value = "";
});
```

```html
<ol id="notes-list"></ol>

<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" id="note" onfocus="this.select()" />

  <button type="submit" form="my-form" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Something to consider, because it's usually good to do this, is to create an inti method and that you then activate with `window.addEventListener('load', methodName)` or as I did in the example below on the `body` tag. However, I can't see how that would be any different than what you have already done.

```js
var notes, submit, ordered;

function initVariables() {
  notes = document.querySelector("#note");
  submit = document.querySelector(".submit-btn");
  ordered = document.querySelector("#notes-list");

  submit.addEventListener("click", addToList);
}

function addToList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let newLI = document.createElement("li");
  newLI.innerHTML = notes.value;

  ordered.appendChild(newLI);
  notes.value = "";
}
```

```html
<body onload="initVariables()">

  <ol id="notes-list"></ol>

  <form id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="note" onfocus="this.select()" />

    <button type="submit" form="my-form" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for any newbie coming after me.

I thought I could use app.js on both my index.html and index2.html ... but it doesn't work that way.

each index needs its own js file.

So heres what i did.

on app.js for index.html, I had it capture the note and set it to localstorage.using a click event.

Then on index2.html, I just added js directly to the file(i guess i could have created app2.js, but it wasnt needed). But all i did was have this js get the key from local storage, create a new Li and appended it to my OL. now it works perfectly.